# iptables DNAT to external IP without masquerading does not work

Tags: iptables, dnat, masquerade

On server 1.1.1.1:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 20000 -j DNAT --to-destination: 2.2.2.2:20000

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 20000 -j LOG --log-prefix pre20k

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 20000 -j LOG --log-prefix post20k
```

On server 2.2.2.2:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 20000 -j LOG --log-prefix pre20k
```

On client 3.3.3.3:

```
nc 1.1.1.1 20000
```

I can see in the logs of 1.1.1.1 that postrouting packages do have SIP=3.3.3.3
and DIP=2.2.2.2 (and not 1.1.1.1 as in original prerouting package).

However, none of the packages delivered from 1.1.1.1 arrive at 2.2.2.2. I cannot see them neither in iptables log nor in tcpdump.

Why?

Comment: The rules look fine, assuming there is no rules in the filter table that interfere with the packet processing. Maybe anything else in between that might kill the packets?

Comment: When I add the following rule, server 2.2.2.2 starts to get the packets: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 20000 -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.1. This means that when packets coming out of 1.1.1.1 with SIP that is not  1.1.1.1 are somehow dropped. What can be a reason? No other rules are defined. Both machines are on digitalocean cloud.

Answer (score 0):

The machines I was testing the rules sit on digitalocean cloud. I googled and found

> "Since it the gateway box is attempting to send a packet that has a
>   different source address from itself, it will not be allowed through."